# Gnome (shell) extensions installed but not showing in Tweaks

Tags: gnome

I have to show students some presentations online. It would be handy if I could draw on the screen to highlight things.

I read 20.04 can do this. So I followed instructions I found online for 20.04

I installed:

> sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
> sudo apt install gnome-tweaks-extensions

I rebooted. Still no extensions in the Tweaks menu list.

I have gnome shell version:

> pedro@pedro-HP:~$ gnome-shell --version
> GNOME Shell 3.36.9

Any tips please?

Answer (score 1):

Ah well, I figured it out!

I have always used Unity and Compiz.

When I login, I can choose Ubuntu or Wayland or Unity.

I chose Ubuntu, then the on-screen-drawing works fine!

Comment: How are you drawing on the screen in a standard Ubuntu install? I am not aware of such feature.

Comment: There was a programme you could install, can't remember the name, then I could use my Wacom tablet. Now, Ubuntu has this feature in the repos. Just follow the instructions above. You must have the Gnome shell running, not Unity. Or just look for "draw on the screen, Ubuntu 20.04" Cool! Activate it in Tweaks, then press Super+Alt+D to switch it on or off!!

Comment: As currently written, your question and answer are of very little use to anyone else but you.